# Applying scale transform to all elements in a table row

Tags: html, css

I have a html document as below.  Just adding relevant content for brevity.

```
<body>
        <h2>View</h2>
        <div class="events-div">
            <table style="overflow-y:auto; height:500px">
                <tr>
                    <th class="content-cardnumber">Card Number</th>
                    <th class="content-eventcode">Event Code</th>
                    <th class="content-origintime">Event Time</th>            
                </tr>

                @foreach (IEvent e in Model.EventList)
                {
                    <tr class="events-row">
                        <td title="Test" class="content-cardnumber">@e.CardNumber</td>
                        <td class="content-eventcode">@e.EventCode</td>
                        <td class="content-origintime">@e.EventOriginTime</td>

                    </tr>
                }

            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
```

And the css is as below:

```
.content-cardnumber{margin-left: auto;color:rgba(47,130,194,.8);width:200px;text-align:center;text-shadow:1px 2px 1px rgb(127, 193, 211);}
.content-origintime{margin-left: 110px;color:rgba(47,130,194,.8);text-align:center;text-shadow:1px 1px 1px rgb(127, 193, 211);}
.content-eventcode{margin-left: 130px;color:rgba(47,130,194,.8);text-align:center;width:200px;text-shadow:1px 2px 1px rgb(127, 193, 211);}
.content-readername{margin-left: 150px;color:rgba(47,130,194,.8);text-align:center;text-shadow:1px 2px 1px rgb(127, 193, 211);}
.events-table{background-color:#aacef6;overflow:auto;}
.events-div{overflow-y: auto;height: 500px;scrollbar-3dlight-color: rgb(127, 193, 211);scrollbar-face-color: rgb(127, 193, 211);scrollbar-base-color: #ffffff;}
.events-row{background-color:#c8ddf5;transition-property:all;transition-duration:0.8s;transition-timing-function:ease;}
.events-row:hover{background-color:white;transform:scale(1.5);}
.content-cardnumber:hover{text-shadow:none;transform:inherit;}
.content-readername:hover{text-shadow:none;transform:inherit;}
.content-origintime:hover{text-shadow:none;transform:inherit;}
.content-eventcode:hover{text-shadow:none;transform:inherit;}
```

Now i want to scale the entire row when i hover over any column. Now what is happening is only the cell that i hover over scales. What change should i make? Is this because i have a defined a separate style for each `td` within the `tr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about replacing

```
.events-row:hover{background-color:white;transform:scale(1.5);}
.content-cardnumber:hover{text-shadow:none;transform:inherit;}
.content-readername:hover{text-shadow:none;transform:inherit;}
.content-origintime:hover{text-shadow:none;transform:inherit;}
.content-eventcode:hover{text-shadow:none;transform:inherit;}
```

with this?

```
.events-row:hover > td {background-color:white;transform:scale(1.5);text-shadow:none;}
```

Comment: This works but slow color transformation does not happen based on the delay configured.!